# how to use try and catch in this code (java)

Tags: java

```
package zed;

import java.util.Stack;

public class decTobin {
    public void convertBinary(int num) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        while (num != 0) {
            int d = num % 2;
            stack.push(d);
            num /= 2;
        }

        while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.print(stack.pop());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decimalNumber = 123;
        System.out.print("binary of " + decimalNumber + " is :");
        new decTobin().convertBinary(decimalNumber);
    }
 }
```

-

I do not understand try and catch in java, please help me to add them in this code so I can understand more.

Comment: In your example code, no method throws an exception.  Therefore, there is nothing to try or catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer is here:

Your code's `convertBinary` method is incomplete. It can convert only positive integer numbers. So you should throw `Exception` if user would input a 0 or negative integer numbers.

```
public void convertBinary(int num) throws Exception {
    if (num < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Number out of range (num > 0)");
    }

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    while (num != 0) {
        int d = num % 2;
        stack.push(d);
        num /= 2;
    }

    while (!(stack.isEmpty())) {
        System.out.print(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

And then, your main method is required (by Eclipse or other IDEs) to implement `try-catch` clause.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int decimalNumber = -123;
    System.out.println("binary of " + decimalNumber + " is :");
    try {
        new decTobin().convertBinary(decimalNumber);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

This is how `try-catch` clause works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this I hope this will help you to way out.

```
while (num != 0) {

try { // checks code for exceptions
        int d = num % 2;

            stack.push(d);

            num /= 2

        break; // if no exceptions breaks out of loop
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { // if an exception appears prints message below
        System.err.println("Please enter a number! " + e.getMessage());
        continue; // continues to loop if exception is found
    }

 }
```

or you can catch the exception like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int decimalNumber = 123;

        System.out.print("binary of " + decimalNumber + " is :");
 try { // checks code for exceptions
        new decTobin().convertBinary(decimalNumber);

  } 
        catch (Exception e) { // if an exception appears prints message below
System.err.println("Please enter a number! " + e.getMessage());
}
    }
```

Comment: You need to switch the location of the `continue;` and `break;` statements.